# Join two datasets by two columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a PostgreSQL query, where I create temp table by joining another temp table, and table from my database.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS other_temp_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE other_temp_table AS
  SELECT *
        FROM base.main_data
        WHERE  period_start_time::DATE >= '2017-06-20' AND period_start_time::DATE <= '2017-07-26';
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS first_temp_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE first_temp_table AS
SELECT *
    FROM _temp_table
LEFT JOIN base."UL_parameters"
        ON temp_table.base_col::INT = base."UL_parameters".base_col::INT
        and temp_table.sec_col::INT= base."UL_parameters".sec_col::INT;
```

Now, the problem is `ERROR: column "sec_col" specified more than once.
But when I delete sec_col join condition and do just base_col, everything is ok. I think that I need to create an alias, but not sure how.

Comment: I don't know the PostgreSQL syntax, but
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS **_temp_table**;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE _temp_table AS
    SELECT *
        FROM **_temp_table**
looks strange to me

Comment: @RaphaelMüllner
My mistake while typing

Comment: You try to join _temp_table but then refer to temp_table (without the first underscore)

Comment: @verhie Thanks, but it's not that a problem, I couldn't copy original syntax because it's under NDA and then I made mistake while typing. I'm not sure how to create alias for sec_col from base.UL_parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that there is a sec_col column in both joined tables. Try to replace `select *` with `select column1, column2, ...`.

It's a good practice to avoid `select *` in general, because it can cause errors when the table definition changes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have change order of tables while join and then select columns, not select *.